# How to check that all the values in a DataFrame are within particular condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex. All values in all the Series within the DataFrame should be either NaN or a real number equal or greater than -a and smaller or equal to a where a is a real number. How do I check this is true?

It would also be great to know the column and/or the row of the first found invalid value if possible but this is not worth any serious increase in code complexity or operation speed decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a  data frame

```
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.randint(10,size=[5]),
                   'col2': np.random.randint(10,size=[5]),
                   'col3': [np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

    col1    col2    col3
0   9       0       NaN
1   4       1       1.0
2   0       8       2.0
3   1       9       3.0
4   9       0       4.0
```

And you want to check whether all values are `np.nan` *and* some other condition. Assuming you have only numbers as columns, you can chain `.all()` for a vectorized way of checking if all cells match these conditions:

```
a = 5
(df.isnull() | (df > a)).all().all()
```

Notice you can add how many conditions you want, for example

```
(df.isnull() | (df > a) | (df < -a)).all().all()
```

---

Detail:

`(df.isnull() | (df > a))` yields

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   True    False   True
1   False   False   False
2   False   True    False
3   False   True    False
4   True    False   False
```

which makes easy to check for where you have invalid indexes. For example, using `idxmin()` gives the position of your first `False` occurrence.

```
.idxmin()

col1    1
col2    0
col3    1
dtype: int64
```

The first `.all()` checks for every column:

```
col1    True
col2    True
col3    True
dtype: bool
```

The second checks for this new series.

Comment: Thank you for a great and amazingly quick answer.

Comment: @Ivan glad I could help